# Getting a gradient outer page edge that is correctly on the outside edge of the page on a two page layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, minipage

```
\newcommand{\gradientbox}[3]{% define func to create the gradientbox for the edge
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[left color=#1,right color=#2] {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \rotatebox{90}{
            \gradientbox{lightGreen}{darkGreen}{% call gradient func
                \begin{minipage}{\paperheight}%
                    \hspace*{ \stretch{1} }{\bfseries\large\textcolor{white}{Book I - Player Information}}\hspace*{\stretch{1}}
                \end{minipage}%
                }% end content of the edge gradient
            }% end rotate
        }% end at page lowerleft
    }% end edge placement
```

So, this is the code I am working with. I cannot find the original source anymore (I found it months ago when I first started playing with LaTeX and now I am coming back to it with a *slightly* better understanding of the whole process. Anyway, what I am trying to accomplish is this effect, but alternating which side based on if the page is odd or even.

I have tried a few different options, such as if\then but they have not worked the way I expected. I am ultimately fairly certain that I am fundamentally misunderstanding the structure of the above code and that my earlier attempts might have worked if I had a better understanding. Regardless, I would appreciate the help (as well as any insight). It is probably worth stating that I am trying to declare this in the header and touch the actual text as little as possible, as that seems like poor design (but I come from an HTML background, so maybe I am wrong on that).

Oh, and this is my includes block:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper,titlepage,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}     % package to use defined colors
\usepackage{tikz}       % package to create figures procedurally
\usepackage{eso-pic}    % package to manipulate images, either by tikz or standard
\usepackage{fontspec}   % package to manipulate fonts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % package to create custom headers and footers
\usepackage{ifthen}     % package to handle logical statements for layout
\usepackage{titlesec}   % package to handle beautifying headings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}   % package to handle margins, ect
```

EDIT: This is what it looks like on the odd pages (which is correct).

[image: code in action, correctly on odd page]

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to look like, but you could make the code more efficient by storing the image in a savebox.

Comment: I edited the post to include a screen shot of the side that is working, on the even pages it is still on the same side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This puts the same box on alternating left and right sides.  Note that the gradients also get rotated.  `\AddToHook` is relatively new and built into LaTeX.

The colors darkGreen and lightGreen were undefined, so I used svgnames DarkGreen and LightGreen.  I disabled fontspec so I wouldn't have to use XeLaTeX (slow).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper,titlepage,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}     % package to use defined colors
\usepackage{tikz}       % package to create figures procedurally
%\usepackage{eso-pic}    % package to manipulate images, either by tikz or standard
%\usepackage{fontspec}   % package to manipulate fonts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % package to create custom headers and footers
\usepackage{ifthen}     % package to handle logical statements for layout
\usepackage{titlesec}   % package to handle beautifying headings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}   % package to handle margins, ect

\newcommand{\gradientbox}[3]{% define func to create the gradientbox for the edge
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[left color=#1,right color=#2,inner sep=0.333em] {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}
\savebox{\marginbox}{\gradientbox{LightGreen}{DarkGreen}{% call gradient func
   \makebox[\dimexpr \paperheight-0.666em]%
     {\bfseries\large\textcolor{white}{Book I - Player Information}}%
}}
    
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifodd\value{page}\relax
  \put ({\dimexpr \paperwidth-\ht\marginbox},0pt) {\rotatebox{-90}{\usebox\marginbox}}%
\else
  \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {\rotatebox{90}{\usebox\marginbox}}%
\fi}
  
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

---

This version uses the everypage package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper,titlepage,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}     % package to use defined colors
\usepackage{tikz}       % package to create figures procedurally
%\usepackage{eso-pic}    % package to manipulate images, either by tikz or standard
%\usepackage{fontspec}   % package to manipulate fonts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % package to create custom headers and footers
\usepackage{ifthen}     % package to handle logical statements for layout
\usepackage{titlesec}   % package to handle beautifying headings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}   % package to handle margins, ect
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand{\gradientbox}[3]{% define func to create the gradientbox for the edge
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[left color=#1,right color=#2,inner sep=0.333em] {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newsavebox{\marginbox}
\savebox{\marginbox}{\gradientbox{LightGreen}{DarkGreen}{% call gradient func
   \makebox[\dimexpr \paperheight-0.666em]%
     {\bfseries\large\textcolor{white}{Book I - Player Information}}%
}}
    
\AddEverypageHook{\ifodd\value{page}\relax
  \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \paperwidth-\ht\marginbox-1in}%
    \raisebox{1in}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox{-90}{\usebox\marginbox}}}%
\else
  \rlap{\hspace{-1in}\raisebox{\dimexpr 1in-\paperheight}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox{90}{\usebox\marginbox}}}%
\fi}
  
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The colors are defined in my document, sorry. When I tried this, it is giving me an error on the \AddToHook line, stating "Undefined Control Sequence - LaTeX error: Missing \begin{document}" and then one on the next line stating it was missing a number and assuming it was zero.

I definitely have a \begin{document} and I just put this in place of my old code with no other changes. I am using XeLaTeX, so I don't know if that is what is causing the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, on reexamination, it puts it on a single page (the first one) in the wrong space. I tested with other types of LaTeX and the same thing. I have not tried compiling twice, as I am using overleaf, and do not have an environment on this computer to do it natively.

Comment: XeLaTeX is not the problem (just tested it).  How long has it been since you updated your packages?  \AddToHook is less than a year old.

Comment: Ah. That is probably it. As I mentioned, I am using Overleaf, and its newest packages are 2020, so it is probably out of date. I will try and get an environment set up on my laptop over the course of this next week to test it with a more up to date version.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Apparently I mixed up which should be which (odd and even) but I was able to fix it, plus I was able make both sides fade down by adding a second mbox and reversing the gradient.

Comment: Do you mean a second savebox, as that was what I was going to suggest?  Much faster than running tikzpicture on every page.  You could even put the \rotatebox inside.

Comment: yes, sorry, savebox. not sure where mbox came from. LOL. Thank you again. Now that I am reading through your code some of the stuff I didn't understand in the documentation is making more sense. Cheers!